# $x+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=e^x-1$

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function satisfying $x+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=e^x-1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then find the interval representing the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 1\le f(x)\le 2\}$

Comment: Please be a bit considerate before down voting. Everyone is not as smart as you are.

Comment: Probably the answer has been downvoted because you show no effort whatsoever; math.SE is not a homework site.

Answer (score 4):

$$\displaystyle \Rightarrow x+\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=e^x-1$$

$$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=e^x-x-1$$

Differentiate both sides wrt $x$,using Leibnitz rule of DUIS on LHS

$$\Rightarrow f(x)\frac{dx}{dx}-f(0)\times 0=e^x-1$$

$$\Rightarrow f(x)=e^x-1$$

Now,$$1\leq e^x-1\leq2\Rightarrow 2\leq e^x\leq3\Rightarrow \ln2\leq x\leq \ln3$$

Comment: I didn't know DUIS, so I searched and found that LHS can be written as $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{ \partial}{\partial x} f(t) dt$, but how is that equal to $f(x)$? Can you please explain?

Comment: Just replace $t$ by upper limit in function and multiply by derivative of upper limit minus replace $t$ by lower limit in function and multiply by derivative of lower limit.Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, thanks I get that. I didn't know anything about DUIS, so it seemed a bit new.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ be a primitive of $f$. Differentiating we get 
$$
f(x)=F^\prime(x)\cdot 1-F^\prime(0)\cdot 0=(e^x-x-1)^\prime=e^x-1.
$$
Now you can conclude.